# Multiple canvas polygon detection map using isPointInPath() and responsive design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, canvas

I have an array of canvas objects that draw correctly. i have three problems:

1. Offset. I have tested the code below in JS fiddle and it works, but when i export it my web page, the variables get skewed. The detection happens, but not in the right place. the page width is set in CSS, and the actual canvas area is centered using a margin:0 auto call, however it is smaller than the page width.

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="780" height="690" style="position:absolute;"></canvas>
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var $canvas = $("#canvas");
var canvasOffset = $canvas.offset();
var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
var scrollX = $canvas.scrollLeft();
var scrollY = $canvas.scrollTop();

var $results = $("#results");

// define the polygon items 
var polyArray = new Array (6);
polyArray [0] =[{x:50,y:236}, {x:200,y:115}, {x:350,y:50}, {x:350,y:300}, {x:232,y:325}, {x:75,y:300}];
polyArray [1] =[{x:350,y:55}, {x:350,y:300}, {x:510,y:300}, {x:510,y:205}, {x:578,y:172}, {x:690,y:96}, {x:650,y:17}];
polyArray [2] =[{x:510,y:300}, {x:510,y:200}, {x:715,y:113}, {x:780,y:200}, {x:780,y:485}, {x:625,y:468}, {x:605,y:456}, {x:605,y:428}];
polyArray [3] =[{x:0,y:446}, {x:284,y:320}, {x:255,y:540}, {x:240,y:566}, {x:73,y:600}, {x:0,y:565}];
polyArray [4] =[{x:355,y:305}, {x:510,y:305}, {x:604,y:423}, {x:604,y:460}, {x:628,y:484}, {x:610,y:513}, {x:587,y:468}, {x:537,y:426}, {x:500,y:400}, {x:447,y:424}, {x:312,y:365}, {x:307,y:314 }];
polyArray [5] =[{x:350,y:425}, {x:415,y:421}, {x:455,y:434}, {x:495,y:411}, {x:550,y:444}, {x:618,y:590}, {x:570,y:616}, {x:359,y:597}, {x:333,y:522}];

// call the function to draw all the objects in the array
define(polyArray);
// call through the array to draw the objects
function define(polygon) { 
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (var i = 0; i < polygon.length; i++) {
        ctx.moveTo(polygon[i][0].x, polygon[i][0].y);
        for (var j = 1; j < polygon[i].length; j++) {
            ctx.lineTo(polygon[i][j].x, polygon[i][j].y);
        }
        ctx.fill();
    }
    ctx.closePath();

}   
function hitTest(polygon) {
    // redefine the polygon
    define(polygon);
    // ask isPointInPath to hit test the mouse position
    // against the current path
    return (ctx.isPointInPath(mouseX, mouseY));
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    // check if the mouse is inside the polygon
        var isInside = hitTest(polyArray);
        if (isInside) {
            canvas.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            $results.text("Mouse is inside the area);
        } else {
            canvas.style.cursor = 'default';
            $results.text("Outside");
        }
}
$("#canvas").mousemove(function (e) {
    handleMouseMove(e);
});
```

2. Detecting which object has been hovered over. What needs to happen is on hover of one the array shapes should effect some CSS/JS. How can i assign an ID variable and detect it?
3. when i bring responsive design into the equation i'm a bit stuck for how to incorporate this offset and the poly co-ords to scale appropriately.

Any point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Paddy, did you ever get an answer which worked for you? Want to share it and help others?

Answer (score 1):

**Question#1: Getting accurate mouse position after the canvas has moved**

Whenever you move your canvas (fex: `margin: 0 auto`), you must recalculate your `offsetX` and `offsetY`  values:

If you **manually change** the canvas element's CSS (fex: `canvas.style.margin='50px'` inside javascript), then you must also manually call `reOffset()`.

```
// cache the canvas's offset positions since the
// offset positions are used often
var offsetX,offsetY;

// call this once at the beginning of your app
// and whenever you change the canvas's position on the page
// (eg call when you change margins, scroll, etc)
function reOffset(){
    var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    offsetX=BB.left;
    offsetY=BB.top;        
}

// have the browser auto-reset offsetX & offsetX when 
// the viewport scrolls or resizes
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }
```

**Question#2 Detecting hovers & blurs over your polygons**

Your `hitTest` function will test if the mouse is currently inside a specified polygon. So inside `handleMousemove` you could call `hitText` for each of the polygons inside your `polyArray`.

Keep a flag variable indicating the index# of the last polygon the mouse was inside (or -1 to indicate the mouse was outside all polygons. When your flag variable value changes, you know there has been either a hover-event or a blur-event. Compare the last and current flag variables to determine which polygon is now hovered or blurred.

**Question#3 Incorporating a responsive design**

Mouse coordinates reported by the browser into `e.clientX`  and `e.clientY` are always in unscaled values relative to the browser viewport.

So if you:

- Click the mouse and use e.clientX/e.clientY to determine the mouse is at [100,100],
- Scale your canvas: context.scale(2,2),
- And reclick without moving the mouse from its original [100,100] position,

Then:

*Using e.clientX/e.clientY to detect the mouse coordinates will still report the position as [100,100] even if the canvas has been scaled and the mouse is at [200,200] relative to the scaled canvas*.

The fix:

You must scale the browser's reported mouse position to match the scaling factor of the canvas:

```
// Determine how much you want to scale the canvas
var scaleFactor=2.00;

// scale the canvas
context.scale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor);

// also scale the mouse position reported by the browser
mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX)*scaleFactor;
mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY)*scaleFactor;
```